# Render final image in pieces (EEVEE)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene which I want to render in 4k resolution however blender crashes every time when I try that. It doesn't crash if I render at half that resolution so my question is if there is a way to e.g. split the final image into four pieces and render each individually with EEVEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be able to render 4k without slicing the image into parts, however here some options:

1. "Slicing" you can create several view layers and always render a part of the image and combine then later in your editing software of choice
2. "Splitting" you can split your scene in foreground, background etc and combine the layers in compositing [blender guru 2.7 sample](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing)
3. "Add-on" there is also an add-on (not sure if it's for 2.8+) [set render border addon](https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder)

[This question also got asked at stack exchange previously](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47274/how-to-render-parts-of-the-camera-view-and-merge-afterwards)