# Blender is crashing my whole system when i try to render big image

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render scene of a simple image with about 60 geosets, that has in total 70k vertices and 90k edges

There are 
- no lights
- extra modifiers ( except armature in static position ) 
- water 
- particles 
- nothing but mere static meshes

So I'm able to render scene without a problem at a resolution of 1920x1080.  But I need it to have 19200x10800, so its 20k or at least 18k+
When ever I try to do so, it renders the whole image, and once image is done blender will crash. I have used the console method for such task, which was like 50 times faster or so. Now instead of just blender, my whole system is crashing and I got blue screen ...

I have 4tb of space on HDD 
16 gb ram 
GPU GTX 1060 MSI 6gb 
CPU FX6300 (6x3,5ghz)

Exporting option is set to PNG, but somewhere I have read that for more safety its better to render into openEXR, so i did it and render was successful, but I can't open this format since it for photoshop I guess ? and i don't have one

anytips how to move on ?

Comment: if you need to read openEXR gimp should do ?

Comment: It is clear that the image you are rendering is at the edge of what your computer can handle. Close all other apps while it renders. You might want to render in sections and stitch them together later on. If you were able to render a single OpenEXR file you don't need photoshop or any other program (photoshop deals with exr terribly) just open it on Blender (either on the UV/image editor or in the compositor) and from there you should be able to export it to any other format you need.

Comment: A free app that can read EXRs correctly is krita.

Comment: To render large images in sections (tiles) read [How to render very high resolutions without running out of memory?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/how-to-render-very-high-resolutions-without-running-out-of-memory/5295#5295)

Comment: I just noticed that EXR was just 3k image which was useless to me 20k EXR was crushing my PC too so i try to move on to rendering it "tile" by "tile"

Comment: Well i have downloaded dat Monster Renderer but im unable to use it with lastest blender version but at least its working for 2.62 so i try to render it from 2.62 but i would have one more question and that would be how to run it from console ? since this is extern addon that has its own button for rendering -a for render in console isnt what i want i guess  ?

Comment: Well never mind Monster Render is crashing too