# Rendering Error with OpenCL

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

so I just started with Blender and wanted my adjust my render so it will use the GPU. At first it didnt work so I updated my drivers and everything was fine. 
So now i just tried to render a full image and suddenly i get this kind of error message and in no scene i am now able to render with GPU.

**OpenCL error: CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE in clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cqCommandQueue, CL_MEM_PTR(mem.device_pointer), CL_TRUE, 0, size, (void*)mem.data_pointer, 0, NULL, NULL)**

Between the time when it worked and it somehow gave me the error i didnt change anything important in my opinion. I just made the render use 100% of my resolution and more samples per pixel and now i always get this error.

I use:
Windows 10
AMD Radeon R9 280  ( driver 17.2.1 )
Blender 2.78

something else you need to know?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> I just made the render use 100% of my resolution [...].

This is an important change, since a higher rendering resolution requires more memory. The error you are getting tells you that Blender could not get enough memory from your graphics card.

If you do not want to use a lower resolution, simplify your scene by using lower resolution textures for far-away objects, using lower subdivition levels, fewer particles or in general less geometry when you can afford it.

Also have a look at the simplify tab in the scene settings:
[image]

Another possibility might be to render your image in parts, like shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/how-to-render-very-high-resolutions-without-running-out-of-memory?noredirect=1&lq=1) or in the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47274/how-to-render-parts-of-the-camera-view-and-merge-afterwards).

Comment: Thank you. I will definietly try that partly rendering.

The strange thing was, yesterday even when i made a new scene with just a cube it wasnt able to render with gpu anymore. i got console errors. Today i tried again and everything is fine again. My original scene also wasnt a really big scene or sth.. but well i guess my graphic card still isnt able to deal with it. 
Thanks again. Gotta go for your tip on partial rendering. :)